# Сравнивать время суток (день и ночь)

Tags: php, datetime

появилась нужда в реализации, ночного режима на сайте, для этого нужно, что бы в методе происходила проверка (if), на время суток, то есть если например время сервера сейчас 19:00:00 то включался ночной режим, если же например сейчас 06:00:00 утра, то он отключался.

Пробоавал реализовать это, задавая время статично, но тогда ночной режим отключается после того как время стает 00:00:00.
Нужно более профессиональное решение, буду рад если подскажете, или подскажете в какую сторону думать.
Спасибо

Comment: Функция date уже изобретена.

Comment: Хак: не включать ночной режим после 19:00 до 6:00, а отключать дневной. Тогда и с 00:00  проблем не будет.

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

  <?php
    $CurrentTime = date("H:i:s");
    $NightTimeStyle = "19:00:00";
    $DayTimeStyle = "06:00:00";

    if ($CurrentTime >= $NightTimeStyle or $CurrentTime < $DayTimeStyle) {
      echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="nightstyle.css" type="text/css" />';
    } else {
      echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="daystyle.css" type="text/css" />';
    }
  ?>

</head>

<body>
 <!-- И разметка сайта. -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, моя ошибка заключалась в том, что я не верно прописал логику в (OR $CurrentTime < $DayTimeStyle) отрезке кода, Ваш пример помог мне это понять, спасибо еще раз

Answer (score 2):

```
if (date('H')>=22 || date('H')<=07){
//ночь
}
else
{
//день
}
```